# Detect if WeChat QR code is scanned

Tags: javascript, html, wechat

I am trying to build an app that renders a Wechat QR code and it will be scanned by a WeChat mobile app to proceed the payment.. Authentication, securities and validations are implemented on the app of course so not everybody can do the scan. But I want really want to achieve is like once the QR code is scanned, the tab with the QR code will automatically be closed or at least trigger something in the javascript. Is it possible?

**Take Note:**

The QR Code is a rendered image that came from an API return

Comment: What kind of "app" are you building? Is it React Native app, or are you using WeChat JSSDK? Native HTML5 does not support QR scanning.

Comment: Actually an app for payments.. Basically, what I want is to trigger something in javascript if the QR code in the page is scanned.. The QR Code image came from an API and all I need is to render it via `img` tag.. So when the code is scanned then I will do a redirect. Is that possible?

Comment: How do you scan the QR image in HTML/JavaScript? Is it based on WeChat's JS-SDK? As you mentioned JavaScript, I guess it is not a native iOS/Android app.

Comment: @shaochuancs, The QR code is an image returned from API and just rendered via  `img` tag

Comment: I have no idea about WeChat payments or whatnot, but the only way to detect this is if some API somehow lets you know that some action has been taken by scanning the code. I.e., you display the code, app scans code, app does API call based on code, API contacts your server, your server sends event to browser, browser dismisses the code.

Comment: @deceze, You are talking about realtime events connected via websockets right?

Comment: That's not the only possibility, but the most likely candidate, yes.

Comment: Yes, I understand the QR code image is returned from API. But do you "scan" it in your app? Or the "scan" is finished by WeChat and you just need to know when someone scan it?

Comment: @deceze Could you point out the other possibilities? Because that method is my last resort.. How can a server send an event to browser besides websocket?

Comment: Server side events, repeated AJAX polling, long polling…

Comment: @shaochuancs, It will be scanned by a certain user using the `Scan QR Code` in a WeChat app and the browser/front-end must know that it was scanned and once known I will trigger a Javascript code

Comment: @deceze, thought so too.. A setTimeout to communcate to the server side

Comment: I understand your question now. This is an integration job with WeChat payment stuff. I think it is better if the document link of that API can be provided.

Comment: Normally, 3rd party payment API will offer a callback method, so that when the payment is done, your code will be invoked.

Comment: @shaochuancs, actually it does involve a callback but it will be just requested on the server side not in the front-end and I'm trying to avoid using websockets for that

Comment: Yes, the callback will be invoked on your server side, then you can use various "push" technologies mentioned by @deceze to notify the message to browser. In summary, the logic is: Generate QR code and register the callback -> User scan QR -> callback fired -> push message to browser.

Comment: @shaochuancs, push message is different from realtime websockets right? Have not used push message before

Comment: "push message" is just a general words, anything that will update information on browser without user interaction will help in your case. It includes websocket, repeated ajax request in `setInterval`, long polling etc.

Comment: @shaochuancs, ok thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic problem in 3rd payment integration. I guess it is [WeChat Payment](https://pay.weixin.qq.com/wiki/doc/api/native.php?chapter=6_1) in your case.

The logic is:

1. Invoke [API](https://pay.weixin.qq.com/wiki/doc/api/native.php?chapter=9_1) to start an order and get QR code image. Please note in the API, you can register a callback URL (`notify_url`), which belong to your server.
2. User scan the QR code image to pay.
3. WeChat server receives the scan operation, try to do the payment work, and invoke your `notify_url`.
4. In your server, the payment success/fail information is received and this information is *pushed* to client.
5. Client receive the payment success/fail information and do the UI work.

For how to *push* information from server to client, there are various ways:

- WebSocket
- Server Sent Event
- Comet
- Repeated ajax request using `setInterval`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort of answering and sharing knowledge!